# UWP Native Compile - This object cannot be invoked because it was metadata-enabled for browsing only

Tags: uwp, automapper, native

With UWP Native compile, my sample is attached and have incredibile results:

http://www.fasthomestore.it/UwpDotNativeIssues-master.zip

1. Unzip attached sample
2. Rebuild all with VS 2019 in release mode native compile
3. All Working Well!!
4. Now
5. Stop debug
6. Enter in the Manage Nutget package for TestAutomapper Project
7. Remove “MyToolkit.Extended” package from project (this package is not used in the solution but it is crucial to make App work)
8. Now REBUILD ALL
9. Start the App
10. Exception is throw:

> *This object cannot be invoked because it was metadata-enabled for
>   browsing only:
>   'System.Func,AutoMapper.ResolutionContext,System.Collections.Generic.List>.Invoke(ClassLibrary3.AnagraficaBridge,ClassLibrary3.AnagraficheSinteticheBridge,System.Collections.Generic.List,AutoMapper.ResolutionContext)'
>   For more information, please visit 
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=616867'*

I have try to modify my default.rd.xml for without positive results.

How can i fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a map between these two different types: AnagraficaBridge and AnagraficheSinteticheBridge, you need to use the following method:

`TDestination Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source, Action<IMappingOperationOptions<TSource, TDestination>> opts);`

instead of

`TDestination Map<TDestination>(object source, Action<IMappingOperationOptions> opts);`

The second method is used for the same type of mapping.

**Update:**

In addition, by my testing, you can simply get the resolutionContext in the AfterMap method to assign the value to the lists from AnagraficheSinteticheBridge class. For example:

```
//Initialize
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AddCollectionMappers();

    cfg.CreateMap<TelefonoEmailBridge, TelefonoEmailBridge>();

    cfg.CreateMap<AnagraficaBridge, AnagraficheSinteticheBridge>().AfterMap((src, dest,context) =>
    {
        dest.Cognome = src.Cognome;
        dest.Telefoni = (List<TelefonoEmailBridge>)context.Items["Telefoni"];
        dest.Email = (List<TelefonoEmailBridge>)context.Items["Email"];
    });

});

......

//map
var result = BridgeDataMapper.Map<AnagraficaBridge,AnagraficheSinteticheBridge>(AnagraficaDataForm, opts =>
{ 
    opts.Items["Telefoni"] = BridgeDataMapper.Map<IEnumerable<TelefonoEmailBridge>>(elencoTelefoni);
    opts.Items["Email"] = BridgeDataMapper.Map<IEnumerable<TelefonoEmailBridge>>(elencoEmail);
});
```

Comment: Thank's for support, but your changes not working for my point of view. 
result.Telefoni and result.Email is always to null
ForMember is used because the elencoTelefoni is not member of AnagraficaBridge

Comment: @BorrieroLuca I have updated my answer, you can check it. I assign the values to the Telefoni and Email in the AfterMap method.